# Edit Youtube Player Flutter - Custom - Flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube-api, video-player, youtubeplayer

I use youtube_player_flutte, YouTube API for mobile app.
How can I remove the red circles on the main screen player of my app (as you can see in the photo below ) or is there another way I can do this?

[image: img]